# Form submit with target="_blank" opens a popup window after ajax request instead new tab

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, web

I need some help here...

Anyone knows how to solve this?: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3BfC/5/

When I submit a form with target="_blank" by defaults opens a new tab. But if try to do it after an ajax request, the forms opens a popup window.

```
(function($) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        var launch = function(p_url) {
            var form = $('<form />').hide();
            form.attr({'action': p_url, 'target': '_blank'});
            form.appendTo(document.body);
            form.submit();
            form.remove();
            delete form;
        };

        $('#normal').on('click', function() {
            launch('http://www.google.com');
        });

        $('#ajax').on('click', function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '#',
                traditional: true,
                success: function() {
                    launch('http://www.google.com');
                }
            });
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this, it looks like a horrible hack.

Comment: Any update on this? We are experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Its not trying to open it as a popup but its blocked by the popup blocker cause open something with `target:_blank` in a new tab is only allowed when it is the direct result of an user input, like click or keydown.

You will get the same result when you try to open it in a setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function() {launch('http://www.google.com')}, 10);
```