# after ajax call the form submit using target blank not working

Tags: javascript, forms

I am having user registration form which performs the user registration such as storing user data etc.. after that form is submited via Javascript using _target=blank. but it popup is blocked. After form submit, it will be redirected to open a PDF.
Could you please advice that how to avoid popup blocker?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form submit with target="\_blank" opens a popup window after ajax request instead new tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458128/form-submit-with-target-blank-opens-a-popup-window-after-ajax-request-instead)

Answer (score 0):

The popup blocker will prevent any new windows that are not a direct result of a user click. You must use some javascript to open a window and then set the form's action to the new window.

```
// attach a click event handler to your submit button
<input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="submitToBlankWindow();" />

// create a javascript function to launch the new window and set the form's action 
function submitToBlankWindow() {
    window.open('about:blank','blankwindow');
    document.findElementById('myFormId').action = "blankwindow";
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: <html:form target="_blank" styleId="prospectusForm" method="post" action="/downloadprospectus.html?method=submitDownloadProspectus">